# Why is my vector of type <bool> only storing 1s?

Tags: c++, vector, binary

I'm trying to put translate a string into a huffman encoding using a huffman map that is stored in an `unordered_map<char, string>`. As you can see, it prints correctly where I am putting it in, but after I `push_back()` the encoding to result and then print it out, it shows up as just 1s instead of 1s and 0s. Any ideas?

I have tried printing it out and decoding.

```cpp
vector<bool> result{};
for (auto i : huffmanMap)
{
    cout << i.first << ": " << i.second << "*" << endl;
}
for (auto word: text)
{
    cout << word << endl;
    for (auto ch : word)
    {
        cout << "char: " << ch << " encoding: "<< huffmanMap[ch] << 
        endl;
        for (auto binarych: huffmanMap[ch])
        {
            cout << "binarych " << binarych << endl;
            result.push_back(binarych);
        }
    }
}
for (auto next: result)
{
    cout << next;
}
cout << endl;
return result;
```

```
a: 0*
c: 10*
b: 11*
aaabbc
char: a encoding: 0
binarych 0
char: a encoding: 0
binarych 0
char: a encoding: 0 
binarych 0
char: b 
encoding: 11
binarych 1
binarych 1
char: b 
encoding: 11
binarych 1
binarych 1
char: c encoding: 10
binarych 1
binarych 0
111111111
```

Comment: What is the type of `huffmanMap`?

Comment: It seems as the value  in huffmanMap you are storing `char`, so if you have `0` or `1` their ascii code are 48 and 49, so when you put data into vector it is always converted into true because both are not equal zero.

Comment: @Shawn huffmanMap is of type unordered_map<char, string>, where char is the character and the string is the binary encoding (ex. "a" and "10")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing digits and numbers.

`'0'` and `'1'` are not `0` and `1`, and both `'0'` and `'1'` convert to `true`.

You can convert a digit to the number it represents by subtracting `'0'` from it:

```
result.push_back(binarych - '0');
```

The digits are required by C++ to be encoded in increasing order without "gaps".